# Fastest way to create a list of unique strings from within a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I have a set of strings (~80 000) I can only access sequentially by the hits.Doc(int).Get("fieldName") method.

```
List<string> idStrings = new List<string>();
int count = hits.Length();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string idString = hits.Doc(i).Get("id");
    if (!idStrings.Contains(idString))
        idStrings.Add(idString);
}
```

The strings will later on have to be int.TryParse()'d.
I think there should be a faster way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, use a `Hashset<string>` instead of a list, the Contains method will go faster:

```
int count = hits.Length();
Hashset<string> idStrings = new Hashset<string>();
```

EDIT: You don't have to call "Contains" if you use a Hashset as it can't contain duplicate items. Just use Add, it will automatically remove duplicate values.

Comment: Agreed - List.Contains() is a O(n) function.  HashSet.Contains is O(1).

Comment: Great, this whas what I was thinking I should remember, but didn't. Hope that makes sence to anyone :P

Comment: Please note there is no overload to set the capacity by an int.

Comment: @Boris, right, the hashset manages its capacity internally, I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`. The `Dictionary.ContainsKey` method is much faster than the `List.Contains` method.

```
Dictionary<string, int> idStrings = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int count = hits.Length();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   string idString = hits.Doc(i).Get("id");
   if (!idStrings.ContainsKey(idString)) {
      idStrings.Add(idString, 1);
   }
}
```

If you use framework 3.5 you can use a `HashSet` instead of a `Dictionary`:

```
HashSet<string> idStrings = new HashSet<string>();
int count = hits.Length();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   string idString = hits.Doc(i).Get("id");
   idStrings.Add(idString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement that slows your code down is `idStrings.Contains(idString)`.

You can try using a faster data structure than `List` (a tree or a hash table, maybe?).

Specifically, you need a data structure with sublinear search time. Hash tables have constant search time, while trees usually have logarithmic search time.